# Error of series is not periodic or has less than two periods, stl()

Tags: r, stl, trend, loess

I have monthly energy consumption data (US) with 295 observations (Jan 1995 - Aug 2019) in R:

```
US_stl1 <- stl(US, s.window="periodic")
```

Got error

```
Error in stl(US, "periodic"): series is not periodic or has less than two periods
```

Checking with previous answers I think the number of observations seems sufficient. Plots shown seasonality appear in the months of December. Also tried `s.window=12` but same error.

Is the issue with `s.window` in `stl()` or with frequency in `ts()`?

Comment: Welcome onboard! Could you please attach some sample data? (`dput(US)`)

Comment: Appreciate your reply! ```21.04 20.01 22.54 17.59 16.44 15.62 14.50 14.23 15.86 17.72 19.07 25.02 21.41 22.70 22.97 18.72 18.11 15.74 14.62 14.40 16.46 18.84 21.37 23.69 23.98 19.99 20.63 18.58 16.20 16.60 16.30 13.46 16.48 18.62 20.19 23.09 21.63 20.10 21.96 19.76 16.96 17.86 15.91 15.94 16.88 18.29 22.03 23.40 22.75 21.12 23.25 18.58 17.17 16.77 16.08 15.20 16.26 19.29 20.88 23.99 23.51 22.12 22.28 19.62 17.69 16.04 15.69 16.38 16.87 19.10 22.32 23.19 24.53 22.29 23.61 19.31 17.43 16.34 15.96 15.98 18.40 17.94 20.79 24.27 23.24 20.85 22.49 18.62 17.09 16.29 16.67 15.22 16.91 18.72```

Comment: Please attach the outputs of `dput(US)` and `str(US)`.